# Why am I getting captcha more often?

Tags: support, captcha

I see an increased quantity of "are you a bot" captcha.  What can I do to reduce the quantity of these?

I use Google Chrome on iOS. I have "save bandwidth" turned off. (This feature uses a caching compressing proxy at Google). I connect using 3G over giffgaff uk (which uses the o2 network).

I have an account with over 4k rep on the [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) site. I visit every day, I vote frequently but not anything unusual.

Comment: Are you using the mobile theme or full site theme? What actions exactly lead to the captcha?

Comment: Are you sure you are still logged in? Search requires a captcha *for anonymous visitors*.

Comment: Any reason you ignore comments?

Comment: @shadow Wizard - i was using the full theme. This happened when answering questions.

Comment: Did you by any chance submit the answers in less than 5 seconds? (copy/paste or just ultra  fast typing)

Comment: I'm getting the image ones several times in a row.  I've had up to 10 where it finally believed me!  Flawed system indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange will think you might be a bot if you...well if you act somewhat non-humanlike. It might think you're a bot if:

- If you click "post" in less than 5 seconds after you start typing.
- If you post a large number of links but not so much text.
- If you post the same thing multiple times.
- If your post is mostly copied-and-pasted content
- If you post a large number of short posts in a row.
- If your post includes links pointing to advertising or irrelevant websites.

Stack Exchange is moving to NoCaptcha, which is an improved version of CAPTCHA where you only have to check a box to prove you're not a bot.

Comment: It might also think you're a bot if you have the gall to decide you want to use the search engine while logged out.

Answer (score 3):

According to my experience it has something to do with blocking too. In my Firefox browser I have a few addons to block certain 'unsollicited' page elements on websites. I am always required to pass the captcha test. If I disable the addons I never get the captcha test. So far I haven't figured out which addon(s) is/are responsible for triggering the captcha.